# search windows 7 programmatically without using an sdk library

Tags: windows-7, command-line, indexing, command-line-arguments, indexing-service

Is there a way to call SearchIndexer with arguments? (or is there another way to accomplish what the title says?)

I tried looking at the various MSDN articles, but they all seemed to suggest that I use a library.  But when I run the search, it runs, without me downloading any sort of library.

Back in the days of XP, you could go to the indexing service properties and execute a query.  I don't see that in Windows 7.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's an example query.  Note that it does not use the Windows 7 SDK.

```
using System;
using System.Data.OleDb;

namespace FileSearchingExe
{
class MainProgram
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {     
string sqlQuery = "SELECT TOP 10 \"System.ItemPathDisplay\", \"System.DateModified\" FROM \"SystemIndex\" WHERE CONTAINS(*,'\"urSearchWord*\"') " +
            "AND scope='file:C:/SomeFolder' ORDER BY System.ItemPathDisplay DESC"; //note the forwardslash in the scope parameter.

        // --- Perform the query ---
        // create an OleDbConnection object which connects to the indexer provider with the windows application
        using (System.Data.OleDb.OleDbConnection conn = new OleDbConnection("provider=Search.CollatorDSO.1;EXTENDED PROPERTIES=\"Application=Windows\""))//queryHelper.ConnectionString))
        {
            // open the connection
            conn.Open();

            // now create an OleDB command object with the query we built above and the connection we just opened.
            using (OleDbCommand command = new OleDbCommand(sqlQuery, conn))
            {
                // execute the command, which returns the results as an OleDbDataReader.
                using (OleDbDataReader WDSResults = command.ExecuteReader())
                {
                    while (WDSResults.Read())
                    {
                        // col 0 is our path in display format

                        Console.WriteLine("{0}, {1}", WDSResults.GetString(0), WDSResults.GetDateTime(1).ToString());
                    }
                }
            }
        }
     }
 }
 }
```

However, it was adapted from the DSearch example in the Windows 7 SDK.  ([SDK]\Samples\winui\WindowsSearch\DSearch.  [SDK] is typically "C:\Program Files\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v7.1"

Note that you can make the SQL query more easily (but slightly less flexible imo) if you use the SDK's `ISearchQueryHelper`.  To use that class and related classes though, you need have reference to `Microsoft.Search.Interop`, which is not included in the Windows 7 SDK as a dll.  You can however get it in dll form by using TlbImp.exe (type library importer, in [SDK]\bin) on the SearchAPI.tlb file (in [SDK]\Lib).  [Also described here](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/windowssearch/thread/0a130e9d-4710-4a72-bf9e-272a3f0128d6/).

I hope this post helps anyone else who needs to programmatically connect to the Windows Search in Windows 7 or higher.